# How to port Windows 8 App on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I have developed an Application in Windows 8 using Metro UI.
 I want the App to work on Windows 7. It is possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not unless you strip off metro entirely and code it using windows forms, which is basically doing it all over.